# Connect to weblogin, how to set cookies?

Tags: html, c++, wininet

I want to log in onto my works' webpage with WinINet.

```
int main()
{
    HINTERNET hInet = InternetOpenA("UserAgent/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,0, 0, 0 );
    if(!hInet)
    {
        printf("hInet Failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA( hInet,"app.tamigo.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT,"","", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);
    if (!hConnection)
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
        printf("InternetConnectA failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA( hConnection, "Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",NULL,"https://app.tamigo.com/Home/Pages/Login.aspx", NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0 );
    if (!hRequest)
    {
        printf("BuildRequestHeader failed %d!\n",GetLastError());
        InternetCloseHandle(hConnection);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
        return -1;
    }

    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

    DWORD dwInfoLevel = HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF;
    DWORD dwInfoBufferLength = 10;
    BYTE *pInfoBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(dwInfoBufferLength+1);
    while (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, dwInfoLevel, pInfoBuffer, &dwInfoBufferLength, NULL))
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            free(pInfoBuffer);
            pInfoBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(dwInfoBufferLength+1);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "HttpQueryInfo failed, error = %d (0x%x)\n",
            GetLastError(), GetLastError());
            break;
        }
    }
    pInfoBuffer[dwInfoBufferLength] = '\0';
    printf("%s", pInfoBuffer);
    free(pInfoBuffer);

    cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```

If this code is right, I have to log in with my username and password, I got a cookie using "Firefox plugin Tamper Data".

How can I set this cookie with WinINet?

Comment: Just as an aside, if you are using c++, there is no reason to use malloc and free. Use the new and delete operators. Furthermore, you do not need to allocate heap at all in this case. Create your buffer on the stack and pass the address to HTTPQueryInfo.

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie already exists from a previous WinInet request, then WinInet will send it automatically.  However, if the cookie does not exist in WinInet's cookie cache (if instance, if you got the cookie from another source), then you will have to use `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` to provide your own `Cookie:` request header before calling `HttpSendRequest()`.

Answer (score 0):

> This is based of @vishalb (I think incorrectly) removed answer. Reposting with more detail because that is the correct answer!

If the default cookie behavior is used, you **cannot manually set a cookie**. Using default behavior you can pass a `Cookie` header into `lpzHeaders` in `SendRequest()` or call `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` but the manual `Cookie` header is simply ignored, because by default automatic cookie handling is enabled. Automatic cookie handling uses a cookie cache that captures system and previously captured session cookies and provides them to the current request. AFAIK there's no way to mix automatic cookie handline **and** add manual cookies.

You can turn off automatic cookie handling by using setting the `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES` flag. If applied you can manually set your own   `Cookie` headers, but at that point no cached cookies are used and any new cookies set are not captured for use in subsequent requests.

IOW, you can have **either** automatic cookie handling that picks up cookies from the system and your previous requests and passes them forward in the same way a browser does, **or** you manually set the `Cookie` headers explicitly. But you can't mix and match the two.